# GroovyCategorySupport and "system" memory leak

Tags: groovy, memory-leaks, jvm, java-memory-leaks

When I run the following JUnit test, the memory of the java process is increasing constantly. After several hours, it uses more than 2go. However, when I look with jvisualvm, the heap and permgen size are stable, I don't see any leak. The test is run with `-Xmx32m`

```
public class TestCat {  
  public static class A { }  

  @Test 
  public void testCategory() { 
    for(;;) { 
      GroovyCategorySupport.use(A.class, new Closure<Object>(null) { 
        public Object call() { return null; } 
      }); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I have tested it with Groovy 2.4.7, Windows and a JRE1.7_80, MacOS and JRE1.7_60.
I can't reproduce this bug with MacOS and JRE 1.8.0_91

I suppose it's related to a bug in the JRE1.7, and I am looking for a way to mitigate this issue:

- my test is maybe wrong ? How is it possible to leak "system" memory without leaking heap space or permgen space ?
- Is it a "known" bug or incompatibility between Groovy and a JRE 1.7 ?
- How to use groovy category with a 1.7 jre and without suffering this memory leak ?

**EDIT**

I can reproduce this bug by calling `VMPluginFactory.getPlugin().invalidateCallSites()`, which translates with this "pure java" unit test :

```
public class TestSwitchPoint {

  @Test
  public void testSP() {
    SwitchPoint switchPoint = new SwitchPoint();
    for(;;) {
      SwitchPoint old = switchPoint;
      switchPoint = new SwitchPoint();
      SwitchPoint.invalidateAll(new SwitchPoint[]{old});
    }
  }
}
```

In fact, only `new SwitchPoint()` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a bug in JRE. Native memory leak happens inside JVM at the following place:

```
(VM)
 - os::malloc(unsigned long, unsigned short, unsigned char*)
 - CHeapObj<(unsigned short)1792>::operator new(unsigned long, unsigned char*)
 - JNIHandleBlock::allocate_block(Thread*)
 - JNIHandleBlock::allocate_handle(oopDesc*)
 - JNIHandles::make_weak_global(Handle)
 - instanceKlass::add_member_name(int, Handle)
 - MethodHandles::init_method_MemberName(Handle, methodOopDesc*, bool, KlassHandle)
 - MethodHandles::init_method_MemberName(Handle, CallInfo&, Thread*)
 - MethodHandles::resolve_MemberName(Handle, KlassHandle, Thread*)
 - MHN_resolve_Mem
(JAVA)
 - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(MemberName, Class)
 - java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(byte, MemberName, Class)
 - java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrNull(byte, MemberName, Class)
 - java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.maybeRebind(Object)
 - java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.bindReceiver(Object)
 - java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeDynamicInvoker()
 - java.lang.invoke.MutableCallSite.dynamicInvoker()
 - java.lang.invoke.SwitchPoint.<init>()
 - Test.main(java.lang.String[])
```

It is a known issue with MemberNameTable: [JDK-8152271](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152271). Unfortunately, it has been fixed only in JDK 9. By a lucky chance your problem is not seen on JDK 8 because of MethodHandles refactoring done in [JDK-8050166](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050166). Although MemberNameTable probem remains, `SwitchPoint()` no longer creates new MemberNames. The latter fix was also backported to JDK 7u91.

Groovy runtime uses MethodHandles if it detects Java 7+. You may workaround this by patching [`VMPluginFactory`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/vmplugin/VMPluginFactory.java#L40) to use Java 6 plugin. Here is the [patch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LUxTf0AV-fWWR2M09ieklRVlk/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-cmWrn0bmqv6bIYKgBt5nTg). If included in classpath before Groovy libraries, it will force Groovy runtime to use Java 6 - compatible VMPlugin.

So, you have the following options to workaround the memory leak:

- use JRE 8 (recommended)
- use JRE 7u91+
- include VMPluginFactory patch in classpath

Comment: Thank you! I suppose there is a side-effect on performances if I force Groovy to not use MethodHandles ?

Comment: @JérémieB There might be performance implications, but I don't expect them to play big difference. Of course, this depends on a particular application.

Comment: The changelog of 7u91 doesn't list JDK-8050166 neither JDK-8144848, and I don't see any commit on mercurial about changes on MethodHandle

Comment: @JérémieB In fact, it was partially backported under the different bug ID: [JDK-8142882](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/rev/c434c67b8189)